# Why the array elements are having different values inside and outside the loop?

Tags: c++, arrays

While doing some code,I am not having the expected results due to self change in array values inside and outside the loop.why its happening?

```
char* arr[2];
int i=0;
char inp[20];
while(i<2)
    {
    cin>>inp;
    arr[i]=inp;
    cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
    i++;
    }
cout<<arr[0]<<endl;
cout<<arr[1]<<endl;
```

For the input :

```
aaa
bbb
```

The output is:

```
aaa
bbb
bbb
bbb
```

Comment: are you sure about your output? Ideone produces a different one, consistent with the already given answers: http://ideone.com/y2YQjX

Comment: @iharob Arrays - especially the encapsulated `std::array` - are very valid in many cases. Sure, for ad-hoc dynamic arrays like this seems to be, `vector` is better, but on a general level - as you've phrased it - I don't agree with either of the blanket recommendations you're making.

Comment: @M.M Thank you for the clarification, I will delete the comment.

Comment: By mistake i had written wrong output in the last two rows..i have corrected it as bbb instead of aaa ...So sorry for my mistake @Anedar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following line doesn't do what you think:

```
    arr[i]=inp;
```

Here you are assigning to `arr[i]` a pointer to `inp`, not copying the `inp`ut buffer into `arr[i]`. During the same iteration (i.e. at the first `cout << arr[i]`) everything is fine. As soon as you overwrite the contents of `inp`, the changes will reflect in all the cells of `arr` you have assigned to that same pointer. In fact, at the end of the loop all cells of `arr` point to `inp`, which means you will always see the last value extracted from `cin`.

As a solution, make `arr` an array of "strings" and copy the input buffer using `strncpy`:

```
char arr[2][20];
int i=0;
char inp[20];
while(i<2)
    {
    cin>>inp;
    strncpy(arr[i], inp, 20);
    cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
    i++;
    }
cout<<arr[0]<<endl;
cout<<arr[1]<<endl;
```

Or use C++ `std::string` if possible.

Comment: Still curious why the two last lines are `aaa`, not `bbb` as expected. Probably a bad manip from OP.

Comment: @mikedu95 my best guess is that OP made a mistake in writing the output by hand instead of copy&pasting it from the output of the program. In any case, the issue here is pretty clear :)

Comment: Yess...It was a mistake...I was just confused that why I was getting bbb all the time... Thanx @StefanoSanfilippo

Comment: Also ..please can you suggest way to store the values that I want instead of modifying them like in this case?

Comment: @Himanshu I am not sure I understood correctly your question.